# Non-Constant Solutions of Nonlinear Elliptic PDE System

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I've left PDE as a field and a friend recently asked me the following question regarding solutions $u$ and $v$ of a system of PDE. Consider
$$ \nabla \cdot (a(u,v)\nabla u + \lambda u a(u,v)\nabla v)=0,$$
$$ \nabla \cdot (b(u,v)\nabla u - \lambda u b(u,v)\nabla v)=0,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary smooth functions, $\lambda > 0$ is a real constant, and the spatial domain is a sufficiently smooth bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $u$ and $v$ satisfy Neumann or periodic conditions on the boundary. The question is: do nonconstant (smooth) solutions exist? If so, what conditions on $a$ and $b$ could preclude nonconstant solutions? I imagine that some positivity assumptions on $a$ and $b$ are necessary to use any tools from Elliptic PDE, such as Maximum Principles etc, but my memory of these things is quite shallow (and I never went much beyond what is in Evans' book). As an example, if $a = \exp(c_1u+c_2v)$ and $b = \exp(c_3u+c_4v)$, where $c_1, c_2, c_3,$ and $c_4$ are real constants, can nonconstant smooth solutions exist?

As a small note, my friend is interested specifically in the case of a rectangle with Neumann conditions on the vertical boundaries and periodic on the horizontal, but any simpler geometric or boundary condition choices should be sufficient to see the key ideas.